# Is there an alternative to temp tables in PostgreSQL to hold and manipulate result sets?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, temp-tables

Within a plpgsql function, I need to hold the result set of a select statement and perform many subsequent *queries* and *manipulations* over that set.

I read about temp tables in PostgreSQL, but these tables are visible in session/transaction scope, while i need my table (or any data structure holding result set) to be locally visible and only exist within the function, so that each function call can have its own copy of that (table/data structure)

I simply need a table alike structure to hold select result set within a function call, instead of temp tables. 
Is there such thing?

Comment: An array of records?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : could an array of records be both queried and manipulated (updating and deleting rows) like a table ?

Comment: Is creating a temp table and then dropping it at the end of the function out of the question? You can create a new temp table (with the same name) and drop it every time you call the function.

Comment: @JSpratt: what would happen in case of concurrent calls to the function? wouldn't those calls act on the same temp table ?

Comment: @Nina - a concurrent query has its own session, there'd be no conflicts between them. Concurrent sessions may have their own (local) temp tables with the same names.

Comment: @klin : I'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Could you do all of your queries and manipulations within CTEs?

Comment: @Jeremy : I don't think so, because that would cause the select statement to be executed for each subsequent manipulation required.

Comment: @klin : i need to return the data set of the temp table as  a return value of the function.. how can i do that before i drop the temp table at the end of the function ?? or should I just drop the table outside the function or at the beginning of it before the _create table_ statement? (drop table if exists [table_name])... create table [table_name]...?

Comment: @Nina Not if it can all be done in one query.  I don't know how feasible this is, but you can certainly do multiple inserts, updates, deletes, or selects within one query by separating them out into different CTEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concurrent sessions may have their own (local) temp tables with the same names. Here is an example of a function which does not do anything wise but creates a temp table, returns its data and drops the table on exit:

```
create or replace function my_function()
returns table (id int, str text)
language plpgsql as $$
begin

    create temp table my_temp_table as
    select i as id, i::text as str
    from generate_series(1, 3) i;

    return query
    select *
    from my_temp_table;

    drop table my_temp_table;
end $$;
```

The function may be safely run in concurrent sessions.

`drop table if exists...` at the beginning of the function is a reasonable alternative. Do not forget to use `temp` or `temporary` in `create temp table...`

Comment: doesn't the _return_ statement cause the termination of the function as in all languages ?

Comment: `return next` and `return query` do not terminate the function. Read more [in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)

Comment: I read that creating temporary tables could be expensive. My function will be repeatedly called to process some text. It will be called from a .NET application. 
Is it acceptable to move creation and dropping of temporary table out of the function, and just create them before the first call and drop them after the last one while connection to DB stays open between calls to function ?

Comment: It's possible and even desirable for improved performance. Also, you don't have to worry about dropping the table because it'll be deleted automatically when the session terminates.